# Is there any way to select all and add cursors to every lines at the end for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to close each line with " and , . I know we can use Alt+Click to add cursor for each line, but there are just too many clicks to do that.

Is there any way to select all at once and add cursors to every lines at the end?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select all lines you want to change. If you want to change the whole file, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to add cursors to the end of all selected lines.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seems to work on my editor. May I check which command does your Ctrl+Shift-I mapped to ?

Comment: @j.f. Oi, sorry, it's Alt-Shift-I. Mapped to "Add cursors to line ends".

Comment: This work damn well with Ctrl+A with Select All! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In menu, click Selection -> Column Selection Mode

Then click end line ang drag down.

Comment: Thanks! I found out how to drag it and it works!